# How to produce and consume a RabbitMQ message with inside Spring RestController and send it back to the user

Tags: spring, kotlin, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

Hello Anyone and Everyone. I am working on a Spring Boot application. Here is my problem. I have a Spring RestController with a post-mapping that takes in some data. I am then needing to send that data over RabbitMQ to another application which in return will perform some calculations on that data and then send it back to me which I then want to return back to the user.

I know that RabbitMQ is for async communication. But I need my controller to return the result that comes back from RabbitMQ all in one go. Right now I am using.

```
@EnableBinding(Sink::class)
class OptimizedScheduleMessageListener {
    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    fun handler(incomingMessage: MyDTO) {
        println(incomingMessage)
    }
}
```

to retrieve the results from RabbitMQ. Now I just need my Controller to return it.

```
@PostMapping( produces = ["application/json"])
   fun retrieveOptimizedSchedule: Result<MyDTO> {

       myUncalculatedDTO: MyDTO()
       source.output().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(myUncalculadeDTO).build())

       return ???

   }
```

Any help with this endeavor is much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Spring Cloud Stream is not designed for request/reply processing.

See the [Spring AMQP (Spring for RabbitMQ) project](https://spring.io/projects/spring-amqp).

The `RabbitTemplate` has `sendAndReceive` and `convertSendAndReceive` methods to implement the RPC model.

On the server side, a `@RabbitListener` method can be used for request/reply.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not advised for couple of reasons.

```
   1. The failure of the 'Another application' which consumes the Rabbit
      MQ messages will result in Requests being blocked on the controller end.
   2. There is a limit on how many requests you can have simultaneously from the server to clients.
```

What you can do is use any other communication protocol than REST for this specific part. May be Websocket will be an ideal solution. If not you need to have two REST endpoints. One to submit and get back an request-id, another to poll periodically with the request-id and get processed, completed response.